# Is there an average size for British postcodes?

Tags: data, geometry, intersection, spherical-geometry, circle

Is there an average size for British postcodes? Or a method of determining the size for a particular British postcode? Thanks.
Considering creating a related program and this would be valuable information.

I'm referring to postcodes like:

1. BT28 1AW
2. LS9 8AH
3. L15 3DE

By size, I'm referring to the amount of area they cover (1 miles - 20miles)

Comment: Please be specific. Domestic or business? Do you mean the full code? Postcodes have 2 components, the incoming e.g. SR2) and the outgoing (e.g 8QS) The number of delivery points reading from left to right decreases until you get a fairly small subset of properties.

Comment: Do you mean size as in area or number of delivery points?

Comment: I will answer the non-GIS part of this question here in a comment. The average size can be obtained by dividing the area of the UK, [which is about 244,000 square kilometers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom), by the count, which is approximately [1.7 million postcodes in the UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Listings_and_availability). That gives 0.144 square kilometers (0.0554 square miles) per postcode. Other answers are possible depending on what is meant by "British" and what kinds of codes are meant, as indicated by @Stevetech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UK postcodes are based on the number of addresses and not area.  Postcodes in rural areas are considerably larger by orders of magnitude than those in dense urban areas. In fact, large blocks of flats can even have more than one postcode at the level you mention, so you then have a problem of multiple postcodes occupying the same area, which in 2D space will be no bigger than the footprint of a building (i.e. a few square meters in comparison to many square kilometers or larger for more rural areas.

As Stevetech suggests, you can identify the exact size of a given postcode by obtaining the [postcode boundary data](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-with-polygons.html) - that is the only method of determining their actual area.  For this you don't need to write a program.  Just plug the data into any competent GIS and get it to spit out the area.  You could create Voronoi polygons around all the [code points](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html) (the point data with limited attribution is free where as the boundary data is not) but they will not bear much resemblance to the actual postcode districts whose boundaries follow natural and man made features that determine postal delivery areas.  If you are not interested in accuracy and can accept a huge margin of error, this is your only option short of actually buying the boundary data.

Postcodes were also designed for delivering letters and no other purpose (although they are misused for all sorts of reasons not related to the postal service), therefore the concept of average land area is meaningless.  If you are not using the postcodes for postal delivery purposes, then I suggest you use some other more appropriate areal unit, though whatever you use, you must be careful of the modifiable areal unit problem if you are wanting to do statistics especially involving temporal comparisons as the name, number and size of postcodes, wards, parishes are all subject to alteration and you need to be sure you are comparing like with like or factor for the changes.  For instance each month about 2,750 postcodes are created and 2,500 discontinued (see [here](http://www.listmark.net/blog/how-often-do-postcodes-change)). At least political boundaries tend to be static for a few years at a time!

Answer (score 0):

The only accurate way to determine the area of a postcode is to purchase the Ordnance Survey's Codepoint with polygons product. This will also give you the number of delivery points within each postcode.